# mongo db sink connector, kafka message key to mongodb document field

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently using the mongo db sync connector.
The key and value format of Kafka messages is josn and is as follows.

```
key: 
[{"EXPUNIT_KEY":"strnig~~",
"INVENTORY_ID":"strnig~~"}@1642398120000/-],
value: 
{"WS": 1642398120000,
 "WE": 1642398180000,
 "NB_IMP_COUNT": 0,
 "NB_ACTIVE_IMP_COUNT": 0,
 "NB_VIEWABLE_IMP_COUNT": 0}
```

I want to put EXPUNIT_KEY and INVENTORY_ID, which are key fields of kafka message, into fields of mongo db documents using sync connector.

If you check the mongo db sink connector document, there is a way to convert the key field of kafka message to mongodb _id, but I couldn't find a way to convert it to fileds(not _id field).

In the mongodb sink connector, is there a way to put the key of kafka message as a field other than the _id of mongodb documents?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongodb-sink connector we need to add the jar file into your libs folder. then, you need to add `plugin.path` in your properties file (either standalone or distribution properties). Afterthat, we need to to run the connector by using below command,

```
 kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin/connect-distributed.sh  kafka_2.13-3.1.0/config/connect-distributed-demo.properties
```

then, we can start the connector by using curl command,
For example, For writing into mongodb your curl command should be like below,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"test-testing-create",
 "config":{"topics":"sunflower",
 "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
 "tasks.max":"1",
 "connection.uri":"mongodb://localhost:27017",
 "database":"flower",
 "collection":"sunflower-collection",
 "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"}}' localhost:8083/connectors
```

Comment: This didn't really answer the question of having the Kafka message key in the Mongo document body value.

Answer (score 0):

> way to put the key of kafka message as a field other than the _id of mongodb documents

You will need a Connect Message Transformation for this

For example, [ValueToKey](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/valuetokey.html) exists, but that is the opposite of what you want.

The only transform I know of that can move keys to values (without writing your own) would be [Archive transform](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive)